# $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ such that $z_1+z_2$ and $z_1\cdot z_2$ are both real. Prove that $z_1=\overline{z_2}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ such that $z_1+z_2$ and  $z_1\cdot z_2$  are both real. Prove that $z_1=\overline{z_2}$.

One of the conclusions is that both $z_1$ and $z_2$ are real. I have successfully completed that.

Comment: What about $z_1=1+i$ and $z_2=1-i$. Then neither are real, but their sum and product are real. Or do you mean that if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are both real then the result works?

Comment: Can you solve that using Z1 and z2 algebraically. Only examples are not enough

Comment: See what I want is Z1=z2 complement

Comment: Z2 complement is represented by z2 bar

Comment: I cannot figure out whats written in your comment because the characters don't make sense. Maybe a problem with the app

Comment: @Rishav When you say that z1
is a complex number you mean that z1∈ℂ but z2∉ℝ, don'tyou?

Comment: Yeah I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $s=z_1+z_2$ and $p=z_1\cdot z_2$. Then $z_1$ and $z_2$ are the solutions of the quadratic equation
$$z^2-sz+p=0$$
Let $\Delta=s^2-4p\in\mathbb{R}$. We have two cases:

i) $\Delta\geq 0$ then $z_{1,2}=\dfrac{s\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}$ and $z_1$ and $z_2$ are both reals.

ii) $\Delta< 0$ then $z_{1,2}=\dfrac{s\pm i\sqrt{|\Delta|}}{2}$ and $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

let $z_1=i$ and $z_2=-i$.  They satisfy the assumptions but are both not real, so your conclusion is wrong. Proving that they are conjugate is easier.
Look at the polynomial
$$(x-z_1)(x-z_2)=x^2-(z_1+z_2)x+z_1z_2$$
This polynomial has real coefficients, thus if $z_1$ is a solution, then its conjugate is a solution and if the conjugate is a different number ( not real ), then it follows that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are each other's compliments if **if they are not both real**( being complex in this case is not strong enough a condition, since real numbers are complex) .

Answer (score 0):

The statement is only correct when assuming $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$; counterexamples are easy to come by.

Writing $z_1 = a + bi$ and $z_2 = c +di$, we have because $z_1 + z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z_1 z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$ b+d = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad ad + bc = 0.$$
From this we get $b=-d$, which we plug into the second equation:
$$ ad + bc = bc - ab = (c-a)b = 0.$$
By assumption $b\neq 0$, so $c=a$. Plugging this into the second equation too gives:
$$ ad + bc = bc - ab = bc - cd=(b-d)c = 0,$$
and by assumption $c \neq 0$ too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got what I needed

Comment: Can you tell me why c+d=0?

Comment: @Rishav That was an error; I edited my answer accordingly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me your academic status?